# File_exist shows error in Ubuntu/PHP

Tags: php, file, ubuntu

I'm a new comer to Linux/Ubuntu so if I make any silly mistake please forgive me.
My code works fine in XP but not in Ubuntu 11.04 (Same PHP/MySQL version)

```
<?php
  if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    header('Location:index.php');
    exit;
  } else {
    if (file_exists("profile_pic/".$_SESSION['uid'].".jpg")) {
      echo '<a href="'.$SitePath.'profile.php?id='.$_SESSION['uid'].'"><img src="'.$SitePath.'profile_pic/'.$_SESSION['uid'].'.jpg" alt="'.$_SESSION['name'].'" title="Me" border="0"/></a>';
    } else {
  echo '<a href="'.$SitePath.'profile.php?id='.$_SESSION['uid'].'"><img src="'.$SitePath.'profile_pic/nopic.jpg" alt="'.$_SESSION['name'].'" title="Me" border="0" /></a>';
  }  
?>
```

If a file exists with name of `$_SESSION['uid'].".jpg"` then show it, else show an default image.

#### The error I'm getting

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_stmt could not be converted to string

Comment: why do you think that it is problem of file_exists?

Comment: Please add the line the error message is pointing to. At least I cannot see any line in the code which echoes an mySQLi statement.

Comment: trust me **THERE IS NO SQL IN THAT FILE** though some of the include file have

Comment: this problem exist in all the page which have `file_exist`

Comment: 1. try to echo $_SESSION['uid']; 2. try to echo file_exists("/ect/hosts");

Comment: How is $_SESSION['uid'] being set? Could you show us the code of where it being set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not showing any database operations, but most likely you've got something like:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = mysqli_query("SELECT uid FROM ...");
```

wherever you're initializing your session data. This is incorrect. The query functions return a statement handle, from which you can fetch the data. In pseudo-code, it'd be:

```
$result = mysqli_query(...);
$row = $result->fetch();
$_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uid'];
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SESSION['uid'])` before the file_exists call.

Comment: The problem is not file_exists. The problem is that you've set up your $_SESSION variable wrong, and have stored a mysqli statement handle, NOT a simple string/number. A statement handle object cannot be converted to a string, so the path you're building is invalid.

Comment: though i did not made the same error as in your example but the problem was with setting the session. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try to print_r($_SESSION['uid'])
that will give you a hint what is it, most likely as Marc B said

Comment: yup bro, you are right, there was prob with session., but same code works in WIndows :P